# Mockito is failing to match when trying to compare Paths.get("/path/to/file")

Tags: java, mockito

In a junit, I need to pass the Path object in another mocked class instance say "foo" and method "bar". which I am getting using Paths.get`("/path/to/file")` so I am mocking it using mockito like below:

```
when(foo.bar(eq(Paths.get("/path/to/file"))).thenReturn(true)
```

But In the main class, it is returning as false. Not sure what is causing this.
Maybe because As I see the Path Object is different even with the same string.

Is there any way I can make it work?

tried other method `same` `refEq` but both did not work.

Comment: Is the `foo` instance that you call this `when` on the same instance as the one you're calling `bar` on? Keep in mind that mocks usually get instantiated per test method.

Comment: Yes, foo is the same mocked class. I verified it in debug mode.

Comment: Can you show your tested code as well as the test? I ran a test with stubbing as you've shown in your question and it's working fine.